# Sending multiple e-mail messages VBA

Tags: vba, email, foreach

I tried the following code (I changed the real e-mail address), and it does work on the first cell in range, but after the first one, it gives me an error says: "run time error, the item has been moved or deleted", and then, it does not sending the others.... what should I need to fix in code ?

```
Sub sendMailWithLoop()

    Dim missmatchCell As Range
    Dim Missmatches_Rng As Range
    Dim entityForRepeatedValues_Rng As Range
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim OutApp As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    If Range("D1000").End(xlUp).Value <> "Name" Then

        Set Missmatches_Rng = Range(Range("D1000").End(xlUp), Range("D1000").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))

        Missmatches_Rng.Select

        For Each missmatchCell In Selection

            With OutMail    

                .To = "mymail@servername.com"
                .Subject = "Attention !! missmatch found"
                .Body = "The missmatch name is: " & missmatchCell.Offset(0, 1) & ", on: " & missmatchCell
                .Send   

            End With

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

thx !!

Answer (score 3):

Move your `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)` inside the `For` as:

```
Sub sendMailWithLoop()

    Dim missmatchCell As Range
    Dim Missmatches_Rng As Range
    Dim entityForRepeatedValues_Rng As Range
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim OutApp As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


    If Range("D1000").End(xlUp).Value <> "Name" Then

        Set Missmatches_Rng = Range(Range("D1000").End(xlUp), Range("D1000").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))

        Missmatches_Rng.Select

        For Each missmatchCell In Selection
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With OutMail    

                .To = "mymail@servername.com"
                .Subject = "Attention !! missmatch found"
                .Body = "The missmatch name is: " & missmatchCell.Offset(0, 1) & ", on: " & missmatchCell
                .Send   

            End With

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives an error for the oMailItem... what actually does it mean ? I haven't found a descent explanation on web... thx !

Comment: Sorry, I made a misspelling error. Anyway you could use 0 as well. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869291.aspx for further explanation.

Comment: can you explain what you did that fixed my code to be working ?

Comment: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(OlMailItem) creates a new mail item. You need to create as many mail items as mails you are sending, so puting that line inside the loop creates as many mail items as mails you send. When it was outside the For loop you were just creating one mail item which only worked with the first mail you were sending, once the loop was hited a second time the OutMail had already gone so it made the code fail.

Comment: Another one.. If I want to create another condition that might (or might not, depends the results of the condition)also send an e-mail, how do I create such condition that wont disturb the objects definitions (dim's) from the first condition ? the second condition is out of the loop of the first one, there's no connection between them both (another IF condition...), thx !!

Comment: You put again Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(OlMailItem) in the new condition

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an error because of OutMail object has a same name for both conditions, and then after I change the object name to have another one, it gave me an error for the .TO line of code..

Comment: Sorry, I am starting to get confused. Could you please ask a new question with the code you are trying at the moment?

Comment: I paste the complete code there: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3c69
Is there are any necessary required changes for this code to be complied and working as well ? thx !